# In pandas is there something like a GroupBy.get_group, but with an optional default value?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame df, which I've 'groupby'ed.  I'm looking for a function which is similar to get_group(name) except that rather than throwing a KeyError if the name doesn't exist, returns an empty DataFrame (or some other value), similar to how dict.get works:

```
g = df.groupby('x')

# doesn't work, but would be nice:
i = g.get_group(1, default=[])

# does work, but is hard to read:
i = g.obj.take(g.indices.get(1, []), g.axis)
```

Is there already a function which provides this?

Edit:

In many ways, the GroupBy object is represented by a dict (.indicies, .groups), and this 'get with default' functionality was core enough to the concept of a dict that it is included in the Python language itself.  It seemed that if a dict-like thing doesn't have a get with default, maybe I'm not understanding it correctly?  Why would a dict like thing not have a 'get with default'?

An abbreviated example of what I want to do is:

```
df1_bymid = df1.groupby('mid')
df2_bymid = df2.groupby('mid')

for mid in set(df1_bymid.groups) | set(df2_bymid.groups) :
    rows1 = df1_bymid.get_group(mid, [])
    rows2 = df1_bymid.get_group(mid, [])
    for row1, row2 in itertools.product(rows1, rows2) :
        yield row1, row2
```

Of course I could creating a function, and I might, it just seemed that if I have to go this far out of my way, maybe I'm not using the GroupBy object the way it was intended:

```
def get_group(df, name, obj=None, default=None) :
    if obj is None :
        obj = df.obj

    try :
        inds = df.indices[name]
    except KeyError, e :
        if default is None :
            raise e

        inds = default

    return df.obj.take(inds, df.axis)
```

Comment: Why not just define your own `getGroup()` method that catches the `KeyError` and return an empty `DataFrame`, I don't know of a built in method that is more readable than using `take`

Comment: Seems like would be easy to write a function. What would you use this for just out of interest?

Answer (score 8):

I might define my own `get_group()` as following

```
In [55]: def get_group(g, key):
   ....:     if key in g.groups: return g.get_group(key)
   ....:     return pd.DataFrame()
   ....: 

In [52]: get_group(g, 's1')
Out[52]: 
   Mt Sp  Value  count
0  s1  a      1      3
1  s1  b      2      2

In [54]: get_group(g, 's4')
Out[54]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not as pretty but you could do something like this:

setup:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  1  8  9
>>> g = df.groupby('a')
```

Now `g.get_group` requires that the key passed exist in the underlying `groups` dict, but you could access that member yourself, and in fact it is a normal python `dict`. It takes the group value to the collection of indices:

```
>>> g.groups
{1: Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64'), 4: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')}
>>> type(g.groups)
<type 'dict'>
```

If you use these returned indices in the index location function of the dataframe, you can get your groups out the same way `get_group` would:

```
>>> df.loc[g.groups[1]]
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  1  8  9
```

Since `groups` is a `dict` you can use the `get` method. Without supplying a default value, this will return `None`, which will cause `loc` to raise an exception. But it will accept an empty list:

```
>>> df.loc[g.groups.get(1, [])]
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  1  8  9
>>> df.loc[g.groups.get(2, [])]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

It is not as clean as supplying a default value to `get_group` (maybe they should add that feature in a future version) but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict` to achieve this.

Let's say you have a groupby object that splits the data on a column being greater than zero.  The problem is all the values could be greater or less than zero, meaning you cannot be sure if 1 or 2 dataframes are available in the groupby.

```
g_df = df.groupby(df.some_column.gt(0))
```

Then there are 2 approaches

```
df_dict  = defaultdict(pd.DataFrame, {i:i_df for i,i_df in g_df} )
df_dict[True]
df_dict[False]
```

Or:

```
df_dict  = defaultdict(list, g_df.groups)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
df.loc[df_dict[True]]
df.loc[df_dict[False]]
```

I haven't tested which is more efficient, obviously the second approach only creates a defaultdict on the index not the dataframe - so could well be more efficient.